# make a program intract with something shown in web page

Tags: explorer

I want to build a program that interact with a web page, For example :

I have 3 lines A, B and C shown in the browser, when line A turned to green
I want to some value in variable. and so on with the other lines. 
I don't want to open the page in my code, the page is already opened in windows explorer, and i want my code to interact with it where it is.

I hope that I explained my question clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I try to access already opened web page using VBA code below but it is not able to get the text.

```html
Sub demo()
Dim IEWindows           As SHDocVw.ShellWindows
    Dim IEwindow            As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim IEDocument          As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim BreadcrumbDiv       As MSHTML.HTMLElementCollection
    
    Set IEWindows = New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
 
    For Each IEwindow In IEWindows
    'Debug.Print (IEwindow.LocationURL)
        If InStr(IEwindow.LocationURL, "file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/demo17.html") <> 0 Then  ' Found it
           Set IEDocument = IEwindow.Document
           Set BreadcrumbDiv = IEDocument.getElementById("demo1")
           
         
            Debug.Print (IEwindow.Document.getElementById("data2").Value)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

As a work around, You can try to refer example below.

```html
Sub demo()

    Dim myIE As Object
    Dim myIEDoc As Object

    'Start Internet Explorer
    Set myIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    'if you want to see the window set this to True
    myIE.Visible = True

    'Now we open the page we'd like to use as a source for information
    myIE.navigate "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\demo17.html"

    'We wait for the Explorer to actually open the page and finish loading
    While myIE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    'Now lets read the HTML content of the page
    Set myIEDoc = myIE.Document

        'Then we'll get something from teh inner page content by using the ID
        If myIEDoc.all.Item("data1").Checked = True Then
        
        Debug.Print (myIEDoc.getElementById("data1").Value)
        
        ElseIf myIEDoc.all.Item("data2").Checked = True Then
        Debug.Print (myIEDoc.getElementById("data2").Value)
        Else
        Debug.Print (myIEDoc.getElementById("data3").Value)
        End If

End Sub
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" id="data1" name="data" value="This is line 1."> This is line 1.<br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="data2"  name="data" value="This is line 2." checked> This is line 2.<br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="data3"  name="data" value="This is line 3."> This is line 3.<br>  
</body>
</html>
```

Output in immediate window.

[image]

Further, you can try to modify code as per your requirement.